# Calling a controller method (from an external email link) that does not return a View, but simply exits

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, controller, exit

I have an MVC 4 Razor intranet app using Windows credentials where a new user must register (existing users are automatically redirected to the main user page).  This generates an approval request email to the admin and returns a view with an Exit button simply saying your application has been submitted. The user then closes the app.

The email is in HTML and presents the user's entered data and has Approved or Declined selections.  It then has a button to invoke code to insert the user into the Members table (if accepted) and return an email to the user with the decision.

Since some time may transpire between the app mailing the admin and the admin making the decision, the session will originally terminate.  I need to have the email invoke a method to persist the new user, email the decision, and then simply exit.  It will not involve the browser in any way, so no Views are involved.  I could write this as a background console app, but that would involve duplicating a lot of code in the MVC app - with referential integrity issues on bug fixes or updates.

How can I write a method in the Controller that can be invoked by a link in the email as if from a browser that does the work and then exits without returning anything to a browser?

If I make the method an ActionResult method and return new EmptyResult() or return(null) I assume it will try to return an empty page to nowhere.

Can I alternatively construct a method in my Controller, where it has access to all of the support code, like?

```
public void EnrollMember(Member member, bool decision)
{
    if (decision == true)
    {
        // insert new user into Members table
        // generate accepted email
    }
    else
    {
        // generate declined email
    }
}
```

and then just link to it the same way I link to Index(), /MyController/EnrollMember(...)?

There is no main() in the app since it is an ASP.NET MVC app, and I don't know how to terminate the app from within a Controller method without trying to return something, instead of from a View in the browser.

I'm a long-time programmer, but a .NET newbie so this probably has a simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

The "view" is just the response. You don't necessarily have to return a *view*, but you *must* return a response. There's no way around that. If the link opens in a browser, then *something* will be displayed, regardless. Even if you were to just return an empty `ContentResult`, at least a blank page will be displayed in the browser.

To achieve something akin to what you're looking for, your best bet would be to return an HTML document with just a simple bit of JavaScript that will act to close the window:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            window.close();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So simple.  I should have thought of that since it isn't even really an MVC question - just an html solution.  Still, it may have to start a stopped browser, invoke the window for a second and then revert to the home page, causing some confusion.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, since the call is coming from an email and not any user's browser just what browser would be opened, anyway?  Without a browser session to "return" to, would this throw an exception?  The problem I posed is how to run a Controller function when there is no browser session - only a link from an email.

Comment: Do I have to return something to a browser if the method is not an ActionResult return, but a void return?

Comment: An email link will simply trigger the default browser on the system to load. There's no exception because the web application is not doing anything here. Clicking the link opens the browser, the browser requests the URL from the server, and the server just responds as normal. It doesn't know or care how the request was made or from where. Finally, yes you have to return a response. There's no way to avoid that. Returning void just triggers MVC to send an empty response body.

Comment: Thanks, Chris.  I'm used to having more direct control over my apps with C/C++ and .NET can be frustrating.  It's like wanting to translate English into Spanish, but having to write it in French and let Visual Studio produce the Spanish - and then going back and tweaking the French to get exactly the Spanish translation you really want. Never make anything simple and efficient when it can be complex and 'wonderful'!"

Comment: The difference here is not in the language, but rather *the platform*. C/C++ is a native programming language, so your application is being deployed on an OS. For one, .NET is just a framework. The language is commonly C# or VB. Those two languages are *also* native, but importantly here, they can also be used with an extension of .NET in the form of ASP.NET. Here, your platform switches to the Web, and it's an entirely different ballgame at that point.

Comment: The difficulties you're having here are limitations of the Web as a platform, not of any particular language or framework. If you're going to build web apps, then you need to learn how the web works, just as you would need to learn how Windows works before developing Windows apps. Look into the TCP/IP and HTTP protocols. Having a good understanding of the protocols that enable the Web to exist will go a long way towards understanding what can and can't be done and why.